# Magento 2 - Web API Create Account

Tags: magento2, api, customer-account, web-services

I use curl to call the web api to create a customer account according to the example [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/get-started/gs-web-api-request.html#request-overview).

```
curl -X POST "http://local.magento/index.php/rest/V1/customers" \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{
    "customers": {
        "customer": {
            "email": "user@example.com",
            "firstname": "John",
            "lastname": "Doe"
        },
        "addresses": [
            {
                "defaultShipping": true,
                "defaultBilling": true,
                "firstname": "John",
                "lastname": "Doe",
                "region": {
                    "regionCode": "CA",
                    "region": "California",
                    "regionId": 12
                },
                "postcode": "90001",
                "street": ["Zoe Ave"],
                "city": "Los Angeles",
                "telephone": "555-000-00-00",
                "countryId": "US"
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```

It returns error as below.

```
{"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"customer"}}
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: These error normally occurs if it is not getting username & password as it's params.

Comment: I added `"password": "123456"` under lastname but it still failed with the same error

Comment: Try this method. it works. http://blog.i13websolution.com/magento-2-rest-api-example/

Comment: @Arjun, it is not the same problem.

Comment: First did you get auhorized token by using est/V1/integration/customer/token then only /rest/V1/customers could be applied

Comment: not accessible by annoymous? as this api is for account creation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43264/discussion-between-zzpaul-and-arjun).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax that works is as follows:

```
curl -X POST "http://local.magento/index.php/rest/V1/customers" \
 -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
 -d '{
       "customer": {
          "email": "user@example.com",
          "firstname": "John",
          "lastname": "Doe"
       },
       "password": "mypassword"
     }'
```

And no, you don't need to pass in any authentication token for this to work.

Comment: getting below error
  "message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",

Answer (score 0):

Format of post data should be as following:

```
curl -X POST "http://local.magento/index.php/rest/V1/customers" \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{
    "customer": {
        "email": "user@example.com",
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "addresses": [
            {
                "defaultShipping": true,
                "defaultBilling": true,
                "firstname": "John",
                "lastname": "Doe",
                "region": {
                    "regionCode": "CA",
                    "region": "California",
                    "regionId": 12
                },
                "postcode": "90001",
                "street": ["Zoe Ave"],
                "city": "Los Angeles",
                "telephone": "555-000-00-00",
                "countryId": "US"
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```

For further information please take a look at the file, *vendor/magento/module-customer/Api/AccountManagementInterface.php*

```
/**
 * Create customer account. Perform necessary business operations like sending email.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer
 * @param string $password
 * @param string $redirectUrl
 * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function createAccount(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer,
    $password = null,
    $redirectUrl = ''
);
```